# How to get around rate limits of publicly available APIs

Tags: rest, api, backend

So I am trying to build my first full website, and my idea for this website involves using a publicly available API. The only issue is that most public APIs have a rate limit of a certain amount of requests per hour, and if I am making direct requests from my application to their API, I will probably run out of requests if I have any users whatsoever.

My question is, is there a way to design the website in a way that could not have the outside dependency? What I was thinking was using this public API to build my own API service that my website uses with only the information I need. The only issue I see with this is that the public API is constantly changing, so I will constantly have to run scripts to update my own API with the correct data and would have to redeploy. Is there any clean way of accomplishing this from a design perspective? Thanks

Comment: You cache, and if that won't work, you pay them for higher rates. Or you provide what they do yourself. It's not magic.

Comment: Rate limits are built into public APIs to stop their servers from being overwhelmed with requests. Some API developers provide paid plans which will remove these limits, but they're there for a reason and I assume that trying to bypass them goes against the terms of service of whatever API you're trying to hit. I wouldn't recommend trying to bypass rate limits. Either cache their responses or find another way to get the data you need.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware that it might be against their terms of service. I recall when I was doing a similar website back in college, we were told to build our own API using the public API and then use that. At the time, I wasn't sure why we were told this, but I assume now that it is to circumvent the rate limit.

Comment: There is another reason for rate limiting free services.  It is to encourage people to switch to the paid version. This is not a bad thing. If there are not enough people paying, the company loses money by running the service (paid + free).  This is typically not sustainable.